# Add numeric column to a date column in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have a problem in Teradata: add a numeric column as months to a date to get a new date column below an exmple:

in input i have

```
a|dat
5|2020-02-15  
4|2020-09-01
```

i want in output

```
a|dat|dat_f
5|2020-02-15|2020-07-15
4|2020-09-01|2021-01-01
```

i tried with add_months() and interval functions but it did not work.
i prefer to not use volatile table but if there is no other solution i will use it.

Thank you :)

Comment: Why didn't `add_months()` work?

Comment: add_months use only a numeric as parameter and note a column name

Comment: `add_months(<date_column>, <integer column>)` should work just fine.

Comment: in fact the a column is the difference between two dates columns ( difference in month) before adding the a to dat column is that the source of the error in the add_months function ?

Comment: Are you saying "a" is defined as `INTERVAL MONTH`? Make it `INTEGER` (or CAST it).